# "Invalid use of Null" when using Str() with a Null Recordset field, but Str(Null) works fine

Tags: vb6, type-conversion, adodb

I'm banging my head against the wall on this one. I was looking at some old database reporting code written in VB6 and came across this line (the code is moving data from a "source" database into a reporting database):

```
rsTarget!VehYear = Trim(Str(rsSource!VehYear))
```

When `rsSource!VehYear` is `Null`, the above line generates an "Invalid use of Null" run-time error. If I break on the above line and type the following in the Immediate pane:

```
?rsSource!VehYear
```

It outputs `Null`. Fine, that makes sense. Next, I try to reproduce the error:

```
?Str(rsSource!VehYear)
```

I get an "Invalid use of Null" error.

However, if I type the following into the Immediate window:

```
?Str(Null)
```

I don't get an error. It simply outputs `Null`.

If I repeat the same experiment with `Trim()` instead of `Str()`, everything works fine. `?Trim(rsSource!VehYear)` returns `Null`, as does `?Trim(Null)`. No run-time errors.

So, my question is, how can `Str(rsSource!VehYear)` possibly throw an "Invalid use of Null" error when `Str(Null)` does not, when I **know** that `rsSource!VehYear` is equal to `Null`?

---

**Update:** If I type the following in the Immediate window, it works as expected (no error occurs):

```
?Str(rsSource!VehYear.Value)
```

This outputs `Null`. Now, I know that `rsSource!VehYear` is actually an `ADODB.Field` instance, but `Value` is its default property, so `Str` should be operating on the `Value` property (which is `Null`). Even the error message ("Invalid use of Null") suggests that `Str` is receiving a `Null` parameter, but how can it treat `Null` differently in one case and not the other?

My only guess is the internal implementation of `Str()` is somehow failing to get the default property, and the "Invalid use of Null" error is happening for a different reason (something other than the parameter is causing the "Invalid use of Null", perhaps when it is trying to retrieve the default property from the `Field` object).

Does anyone have a more detailed, technical explanation for what is actually happening here?

In short:

```
?Str(rsSource!VehYear)
```

throws an "Invalid use of Null" error when `rsSource!VehYear` is `Null`, but

```
?Str(rsSource!VehYear.Value)
```

returns `Null`.

However, both `Trim(rsSource!VehYear)` and `Trim(rsSource!VehYear.Value)` return `Null`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Str function will specifically check if a Null value is passed in and deal with it accordingly. When you pass in an object it attempts to convert the result of a default method to a String. The result of the default method is not passed into the Str method, but Field object is, so a check for the initial Null will fail. The Str function will continue to check the parameter type for datatypes that it supports when it realizes that it has an object, it will attempt to retrieve the default value. It doesn't re-attempt to deal with the default value as it did with the passed in argument, so the attempt to return a Null as a String will fail. It seems MS didn't expect a default value to be Null or any other invalid value for Str. For instance Str doesn't support an empty string either.

Comment: That clears things up. By the way, thanks for SimplyVBUnit ;)

Answer (score 8):

If you need a value other than a string, try using IsNull instead:

```
rsTarget!VehYear = IIf(IsNull(rsSource!VehYear), 0, rsSource!VehYear)
```

' Note 0 is the default value

Answer (score 1):

This was my workaround in the vb6-days:

```
rsTarget!VehYear = Trim(Str(rsSource!VehYear & ""))
```

the **& ""** will make sure there is allways at least an empty string to work with.

Comment: I know I can work around the issue, and in this case I can actually just remove the calls to `Trim` and `Str` altogether since the database field is actually a numeric field. I am more interested in the technical reasons why the code in the question does not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

From memory, null database fields are `Nothing` (or possibly `vbNull`), which do not have the same rules applied to them as `Null`. You should just be able to do a quick check:

```
If (rsSource!VehYear Is Nothing) Then
    ' Null
Else
    ' Not null
End If
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but the field is definitely equal to `Null`. I checked by hovering over it in the IDE, and by printing it out to the Immediate window.